# How To Make A Menu Where The User Can Select Multiple Choices?

Tags: html, webforms

For this webpage I'm working on, I need to have a menu where the user can select multiple items from the list. For example, it would have all the days of the month, and the user would be able to select say the 1st, 4th and 12th.

The only thing that I have tried is a simple menu like this, but this only allows the user to select one particular item. How do I make it so that they can select more than one?

```
<form method ='get' action = "pickDay">
Day: <select name="to">
   <option value="March1">March 1st</option>
   <option value="March2">March 2nd</option>
   <option value="March3">March 3rd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could use the `multiple` attribute on your `<select>` element, but is there a specific menu that you've seen before which you wanted to reproduce?

Comment: Nope, don't care which type of form it is, but how would I include that? Sorry never used that before.

Comment: If you don't know what you want the menu to look like, I don't think I can be of any help. Your question is too open ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <select name="computers" multiple>
      <option value="PC">PC</option>
      <option value="MAC">MAC</option>
      <option value="TAB">TAB</option>
      <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
    </select>

<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>
```